# Automatically Coloring the Java Keywords when i am open a file in JTextpane

Tags: java, swing, colors, keyword, jtextpane

i want apply the colors to the java keywords. When i am open a file it raise the Attempt to mutate in notification exception and program not shown completely and colors also not applied.
Here is my code,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class JavaKeywordsColor extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private JTextPane textPane;
    private Color color = Color.BLACK;
    private int i = 0;
    private JPanel noWrapPanel;
    private JScrollPane scrollpane;
    private JTextField status;
    private StyledDocument d;
    private String[] keywords = {"import ", "class ", "int ", "public ", "private"};

    public JavaKeywordsColor() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        tp = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        Open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jMenu1.setText("File");
        Open.setText("Open");
        Open.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                OpenActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(Open);
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);
        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(JavaKeywordsColor.this, "Select File", FileDialog.LOAD);
        fd.setVisible(true);
        String title;
        String sts;
        if (fd.getFile() != null) {
            sts = fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile();
            title = fd.getFile();
            BufferedReader br = null;
            StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("");
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sts));
                String line;
                try {
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        str.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JavaKeywordsColor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JavaKeywordsColor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            String t = str.toString();
            final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("", true, true);
            textPane = new JTextPane();
            // textPane.setEditorKit(new WrapEditorKit());
            d = textPane.getStyledDocument();
            d.addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                    jColorActionPerformed(de);
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                    jColorActionPerformed(de);
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                    jColorActionPerformed(de);
                }
            });
            Document doc = textPane.getDocument();
            textPane.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 13));
            internalFrame.add(textPane);
            i += 1;
            internalFrame.setName("Doc" + i);
            this.add(new javax.swing.JScrollPane(textPane));
            noWrapPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            noWrapPanel.add(textPane);
            scrollpane = new JScrollPane(noWrapPanel);
            internalFrame.add(scrollpane);
            internalFrame.setTitle(title);
            tp.add(internalFrame);
            tp.setSelectedIndex(i - 1);
            internalFrame.setVisible(true);
            textPane.setText(t);
        }
    }

    private void jColorActionPerformed(DocumentEvent evt) {
        replace(textPane);
    }

    public void replace(javax.swing.JTextPane jp) {
        int cur = jp.getCaretPosition();
        StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
        AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.BLUE);
        for (int ii = 0; ii < keywords.length; ii++) {
            int fromIndex = 0;
            String msg = keywords[ii];
            int nol = 0;     //number of lines upto keyword
            int len = 1;
            while (len != -1) {
                len = jp.getText().indexOf(msg, fromIndex);
                jp.setSelectedTextColor(Color.RED);
                if (len != -1) {
                    try {
                        nol = countLine(jp.getText(0, len + 1));
                    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                        break;
                    }
                    fromIndex = len + msg.length();
                    System.out.println("len = " + len + " nol=" + nol);
                    len -= nol;
                    jp.select(len, len + msg.length());
                    System.out.println("Selected Text = " + jp.getSelectedText());
                    jp.replaceSelection("");
                    jp.setCaretPosition(len);
                    jp.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
                    jp.replaceSelection(msg);
                }
            }
        }
        aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.BLACK);
        jp.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
        jp.setCaretPosition(cur);
    }

    public int countLine(String str) {
        int n = 0;
        for (int ii = 0; ii < str.length(); ii++) {
            if (str.charAt(ii) == '\n') {
                n++;
            }
        }
        return n;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JavaKeywordsColor().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem Open;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The message of the exception makes it pretty clear. You are not allowed to mutate the document while the listener notification is in progress. The reason is quite clear: the modification would trigger new notifications and in programs like yours, either a `StackOverflowError` or an infinite loop would be provoked. It also implies that the might be reports for newer modifications at a time where other listeners not yet have learned about the old ones.

You have to schedule the modification to a later time and protect your code from reacting on your own modifications. Scheduling the update to a later time can also help regarding the performance when the user is typing fastly as you don’t want to parse an entire document on every inserted character.

So you should replace the part where you add the `DocumentListener`

```
d.addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
        jColorActionPerformed(de);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
        jColorActionPerformed(de);
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
        jColorActionPerformed(de);
    }
});
```

to something like this:

```
final class UpdateTrigger implements DocumentListener, ActionListener {
  final Timer timer=new Timer(150, this);
  boolean enabled=true;
  UpdateTrigger() {
    timer.setRepeats(false);
  }
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    if(enabled) timer.restart();
  }
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    if(enabled) timer.restart();
  }
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    if(enabled) timer.restart();
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    enabled=false;
    try { jColorActionPerformed(null); }
    finally { enabled=true; }
  }
}
d.addDocumentListener(new UpdateTrigger());
```

You might find out then that your code has more issues which are beyond the scope of your question. By the way, just highlighting keywords is not enough for a correct syntax highlighting. You need a parser which understands the syntactical structure, especially comments and `String` literals, even for the minimum highlighting.

You should study [Chapter 3 of the The Java® Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html) to get the complete picture.

Comment: DocumentFilter is designated for changes inside Document, then is useless Swing Timer, btw period at 150 is very short for JTextComponent it should be > 500 or usage of invokeLater instead

Comment: @mKorbel: you may use `DocumentFilter` whereas I would prefer to implement an appropriate `StyledDocument` (or a complete `EditorKit`) instead. But my answer focuses on the way the questioner has implemented it. Btw. if you think 150ms are too short, how ought a `DocumentFilter` which has to do the parsing *immediately* come into play? Btw. Swing’s `Timer` will automatically invoke the `ActionListener` at a later time if the EDT is busy. To me, a delay of more than 250ms (when EDT is not busy) is unacceptable for an interactive application.

Comment: Swing Timer doesn't guarantee that event will be executed at the end of EDT, this is job for invokeLater otherwise isn't possible to ordering for one event, DocumentFilter is mentioned there as notifier for listening the changes inside Document with intention to change/modify/append, I see there many times (I think this is mistake because DocumentListener is designated to distribute an event from/out of Document to GUI not to itself) to use DocumentListener and to invoke events back, to own Document and delayed by Swing Timer or invokeLater,

Comment: :-) especially StanislavL loves invokeLater in DocumentListener, in his workarounds for JTextComponents

Comment: @mKorbel: Swing Timer guarantees to invoke the `ActionListener` on the EDT and that’s only possible when the EDT is not doing something else. Further it guarantees not to invoke the `ActionListener` before the specified time has elapsed which is more than `invokeLater` provides. Ordering guarantees are not required, in fact, the code of my answer will miss updates *intentionally* as it cancels and reschedules pending updates using `Timer.restart()`. In contrast, it is impossible to cancel pending `invokeLater` activities. But I agree, modifying the source of an event is bad design anyway.

Comment: @mKorbel: so you are refering to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10006199/2711488)?

Comment: :-) anyway +1 for clear & simple solution for OP, that swaps events in Document to the pieces, however or anything I wrote here to your address

Comment: thank you, colors are applied but when i open a program, it shouldn`t open correctly, missing the some characters, adding the unnecessary code. please help me, how to open the program correctly with colors.