# Java: Attempt to mutate in notification in JComboBox document listener

Tags: java, jcombobox, documentlistener

I need to create a editable `JComboBox` that show data from SqLite database, that matches to typed text in `JComboBox`. I Used `DocumentListener` and it worked but I got an Exception like  below:

> Attempt to mutate in notification

This is my code,

```
org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(jComboBox1);

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                final JTextComponent tcA = (JTextComponent) jComboBox1.getEditor().getEditorComponent();

                tcA.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                         try {
                            SQDB s = new SQDB();

                            ResultSet rs = s.getData("SELECT e_word FROM words WHERE e_word LIKE '" + tcA.getText()+ "%'");

                            while (rs.next()) {
                                jComboBox1.addItem(rs.getString("e_word"));
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    }

                });

            }
        });
```

How to solve this Exception. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java attempt to mutate in notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005954/java-attempt-to-mutate-in-notification)

Comment: I used invokeLater() method here. but same error